# If I'm streaming video: I'm the server or the client?

Tags: streaming

If I'm streaming video from my phone to Periscope's servers: is my phone being a server and listening on a random port or I'm just sending my stream?

For example: VLC makes your device a streaming server, does Periscope do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, your phone is just uploading a stream to their (Periscope's) service, from which it's being distributed to anyone who's watching it.

This is the way such "live-streaming" usually works. A user's upload bandwidth isn't usually sufficient for streaming to multiple clients, but their servers are.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about Periscope being the only client downloading the stream but it makes sense to be the client instead. I dont know why VLC doesn't allow to send the stream to somewhere then.